# Stuck in a loop, freezing the android app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, freeze

I found out that when i pressed a button to run a while loop, the android app will freeze although the program can run. It seem that i stuck in a loop and i want to make a thread to show the GUI and the other for the main code . I'm new in java and i'm self-learned so i would appreciated if anyone could give me an example how to prevent the app from freezing.

I'm sorry if i didn't explain my problem well.

Thank you

Here is my code

```
public class TachoCount extends Thread {
public boolean isConnected;
protected static final String TAG = "TachoCount";


NXTConnector conn;
//_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
//final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

public static NXTConnector connect(final CONN_TYPE connection_type) {
    Log.d(TAG, " about to add LEJOS listener ");

    NXTConnector conn = new NXTConnector();
    conn.setDebug(true);
    conn.addLogListener(new NXTCommLogListener() {

        public void logEvent(String arg0) {
            Log.e(TAG + " NXJ log:", arg0);
        }

        public void logEvent(Throwable arg0) {
            Log.e(TAG + " NXJ log:", arg0.getMessage(), arg0);
        }
    });

    switch (connection_type) {
        case LEGO_LCP:
            conn.connectTo("btspp://NXT", NXTComm.LCP);
            break;
        case LEJOS_PACKET:
            conn.connectTo("btspp://");
            break;
    }

    return conn;

}

public TachoCount() {

}




public void closeConnection() {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "TachoCount run loop finished and closing");
        conn.getNXTComm().close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {

        conn = null;
    }

}

public void establishConnection(){
    conn = TachoCount.connect(CONN_TYPE.LEGO_LCP);
    NXTCommand.getSingleton().setNXTComm(conn.getNXTComm());
    NXTInfo info = conn.getNXTInfo();
    if (info.connectionState== NXTConnectionState.LCP_CONNECTED)
    {
        isConnected = true;
        // set 
        //textView.setText("NXT is here");
    }

}

public void forward(){

    Motor.A.setSpeed(300);
    Motor.C.setSpeed(300);
    Motor.A.forward();
    Motor.C.forward();

}

public void backward(){
    Motor.A.setSpeed(300);
    Motor.C.setSpeed(300);
    Motor.A.backward();
    Motor.C.backward();

}

public void byebye(){
    Motor.A.stop();
    Motor.C.stop();


}


public int getSensorValue()
{
    int val = 0;
    LightSensor ls = new LightSensor(SensorPort.S3);
    val = ls.readValue();
    return val;

}

public void linefollower()
{
    run();
}

public void run()
{   

    int  min = 30, max = 37, readLight = 0, Mspeed = 90, Mspeed2 = 20;
        LightSensor ls = new LightSensor(SensorPort.S3);


        while(true){


                Motor.A.forward();
                Motor.C.forward();

                readLight = ls.readValue();
                LeJOSDroid.sendMessageToUIThread("Sensor: "+ls.readValue());

                if (readLight < min){
                readLight = min+1;
                }

                if (max < readLight){
                readLight = max-1;
                }

                    Motor.C.setSpeed(Mspeed + (Mspeed2 * (readLight - min)));
                    Motor.A.setSpeed(Mspeed + (Mspeed2 * (max - readLight)));   


        }
}
```

> i tried to change the code. It runs well (although the reading of the
>   sensor doesn't seem accurate), but then when i push another button,
>   nothing happens

```
public void linefollower()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
}


Runnable runnable = new Runnable ()
{   
    public void run(){
    int  min = 30, max = 37, readLight = 0, Mspeed = 90, Mspeed2 = 20;
        LightSensor ls = new LightSensor(SensorPort.S3);


        while(true){


                Motor.A.forward();
                Motor.C.forward();

                readLight = ls.readValue();
                LeJOSDroid.sendMessageToUIThread("Sensor: "+ls.readValue());

                if (readLight < min){
                readLight = min+1;
                }

                if (max < readLight){
                readLight = max-1;
                }

                    Motor.C.setSpeed(Mspeed + (Mspeed2 * (readLight - min)));
                    Motor.A.setSpeed(Mspeed + (Mspeed2 * (max - readLight)));       

        }

    }



};
```

Comment: infinite loop ?? i think there is no break condition from loop `while(true)`

Comment: How do you start the Thread?

Answer (score -1):

Try using Runnable or background worker

Answer (score -1):

Your loop looks infinite, it's always true. Also, it's probably better to do heavy tasks in an asynctask activity.

Check the official info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html